# Google Maps Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

How can I make my map initial position to show the marker at the center of it?
My initial camera postion I am using default:

```
LatLng _mapStartingPosition = LatLng(64.139015, -21.928318)
```

```
GoogleMap(
     mapToolbarEnabled: false,
     initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _mapStartingPosition,
          zoom: 11.0,
     ),
     markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
     circles: Set.from(allCircles),
     onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _mapController.complete(controller);
     },
),
```

Once I get the marker I set the initial position according to Marker's LatLng.

```
...
_mapStartingPosition = LatLng(item['latitude'], item['longitude']);
...
```

The map's position updates successfully, but instead of showing marker at the center it always shows it at the left top corner. How can I center it?

[image]

[image]

Instead I would like to show it this way:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You maybe try with:

```
GoogleMapController googleMapController;
      ....
      onMapCreated: (_googleMapController) {
        googleMapController = _googleMapController;
        _googleMapController.moveCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newLatLng(_mapStartingPosition)
        );
      },
```

And when get new Position

```
...
_mapStartingPosition = LatLng(item['latitude'], item['longitude']);
googleMapController.moveCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newLatLng(_mapStartingPosition)
            );
...
```

Comment: Didn't really change anything. It always shows the marker at the top left corner. I think it's the way Google Map processes the LatLng. 
If I give it a markers position it takes it as an anchor point and than show the rest of the map based on zoom from that point. It doesn't understand it as a center.
But I'm not sure, it's just my understanding.

Comment: I found a workaround. I'm just modifying longitude like this:
_mapStartingPosition = LatLng(item['latitude'], item['longitude'] - 00.01);

It centers the markers right now, but to be honest I don't like this workaround personally. Will keep digging for a better solution.